# Iterative method for solving equation

Tags: roots, transcendental-equations

Given an equation such as $4x = e^x $, I remember from high school that we pick some initial point $x = x_0$ and iteratively evaluate $x_{n+1} = \frac{1}{4} e^{x_n} $ until convergence. If the solution does not converge, try different initial points.

What is the name of such class of methods (iterative method? ) and why do these work?

Comment: [Fixed point iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_iteration). They can be guaranteed to work, for example, in cases where the conditions of [Banach fixed point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem) are satisfied.

Comment: This equation can be solved using the product Logarithm function.